# I can't delete or start/use the pulseeffects package, any help?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

```
octacinth@octacinth-Inspiron-14-3452:~$ sudo apt purge pulseeffects
[sudo] password for octacinth: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calf-plugins gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects
  gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects
  gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects libebur128-1 libzita-convolver3
  mda-lv2 rubberband-ladspa zam-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pulseeffects*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,322 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'gimp-data' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This is what it says any time I try to delete `pulseeffects`.

EDIT: Turns out it isn't just an error with `pulseeffects`, my whole `apt` package is screwed, can't download anything, update or remove anything.

Comment: Try to reinstall gimp-data

Comment: I can't, I can't do anything to do with packages it says the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on this link! I just had to manually remove the broken package.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu